# Apt-get Error: Timeout was reached

Tags: apt, timeout

Yesterday, I noticed that whenever I run the command `apt-get update`, everything seems to work until the last step.

I get the usual output:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                              
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                     
Ign:4 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                                                                
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                          
Hit:6 http://apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                               
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                              
Get:9 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial Release [6,600 B]
...
```

However, towards the end and after I get:

```
Fetched X kB in Ys (69.7 kB/s)
```

There is a long delay after which I get

```
Error: Timeout was reached
Reading package lists... Done
```

---

What is causing this? How can I fix this issue?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt update` again? It should be fixed now.

Comment: it may be related to this bug .. I ran into it yesterday [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for me was to kill `appstreamcli`. I did the following:

```
> ps -aux | grep appstream
root      2351  0.0  0.0  21296   956 pts/4    S+   10:03   0:00 grep --color=auto appstream
root     24008  0.0  0.0   4508   712 ?        SN   May19   0:00 sh -c if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi
root     24010 37.1  0.2 144404 38104 ?        RN   May19 281:49 appstreamcli refresh
> kill -15 24010
```

Finally, after running `apt-get update`, the output is now

```
Fetched 294 kB in 1s (162 kB/s)                                  
Reading package lists... Done
```

As expected. Thanks everyone!

Comment: didn't work for me, the PID is changing all the time. In spite of that, I didn't voted down.

Comment: @Rho, sorry to hear that. This is the solution that worked for me (the OP), so there is little hope that it will work the same for everyone. As for the downvote, no worries I was aware a year ago when it was downvoted.

Comment: This is happening to me, but there is no appstreamcli...

Comment: for me it was my security policy blocking a thread clone...
```clone(child_stack=null, flags=clone_child_cleartid|clone_child_settid|sigchld, child_tidptr=0x7f1a9e52bed0) = 12189
wait4(12189, error: timeout was reached
[{wifexited(s) && wexitstatus(s) == 0}], 0, null) = 12189
--- sigchld {si_signo=sigchld, si_code=cld_exited, si_pid=12189, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```