# apt-get install: Error: Timeout was reached

Tags: apt, timeout

Why when using apt-get install I frequently see the error `Timeout was reached`?

```
v@v-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install chrony
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 libcrystalhd3 libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libllvm10 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0
  libnm-util2 libnode64 libopts25 nodejs nodejs-doc python-cairo
  python-configparser python-decorator python-enum34 python-gi python-gi-cairo
  python-ipython-genutils python-olefile python-pathlib2 python-pexpect
  python-pil python-ptyprocess python-pygments python-scandir python-wcwidth
  python3-scour qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin scour sntp
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  ntp
The following NEW packages will be installed
  chrony
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 1 to remove and 9 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/220 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,486 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: ntp: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 systemd depends on systemd-timesyncd | time-daemon; however:
  Package systemd-timesyncd is not installed.
  Package time-daemon is not installed.
  Package systemd-timesyncd which provides time-daemon is not installed.
  Package openntpd which provides time-daemon is not installed.
  Package ntp which provides time-daemon is to be removed.
  Package chrony which provides time-daemon is not installed.

(Reading database ... 249546 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ntp (1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package chrony.
(Reading database ... 249493 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chrony_3.5-6ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chrony (3.5-6ubuntu6.2) ...
Setting up chrony (3.5-6ubuntu6.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.6) ...
Error: Timeout was reached
```

When repeating the command, however, I see that the package has been installed successfully:

```
@v-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install chrony
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
chrony is already the newest version (3.5-6ubuntu6.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 libcrystalhd3 libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libllvm10 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0
  libnm-util2 libnode64 libopts25 nodejs nodejs-doc python-cairo
  python-configparser python-decorator python-enum34 python-gi python-gi-cairo
  python-ipython-genutils python-olefile python-pathlib2 python-pexpect
  python-pil python-ptyprocess python-pygments python-scandir python-wcwidth
  python3-scour qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin scour sntp
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 9 not to upgrade.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt-get Error: Timeout was reached](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775224/apt-get-error-timeout-was-reached)